# How do you produce sign for set multiplication (from old math book) in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm reading an old book on Mathematical analysis and in the chapter on sets I found this:

[image]

This represents set multiplication and I want to reproduce this in my notes, but can't seem to find a way to do that. How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Use the `\DeclareMathOperator` command with the proper sign (a scales `\times` sign here I would say). See for instance: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50669/regularized-product-symbol

Comment: `\varprod` is provided by the packages `txfonts` and `pxfonts`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `\varprod` operator provided by the packages `txfonts`/`pxfonts` and a `\bigtimes` operator provided by the package `mathabx`.

Unless you want to load one of the mentioned packages for any other need, I suggest you to "extract" the definition of the symbol from the package and use it as in the following MWE. Choose the one you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \varprod
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{txexa}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varprod}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{16}

% \bigtimes
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{1}{mathx}{"91}

\begin{document}
\[\varprod^{N}_{n-1} X_n \quad \bigtimes^{N}_{n-1} X_n\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), you can get it with `\bigtimes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[ \bigtimes_{n=1}^N X_n \]
\end{document}
```